# Parse: reset password token

Tags: parse-platform, password-recovery

Okay, I've googled all the things and can't find this anywhere. Super appreciative if anyone here knows:

What is the validation period for the 'reset password' link generated by [requestPasswordReset](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.User.html#methods_requestPasswordReset) using Parse?

From what I can tell, this isn't configurable, but I still need to handle expired links.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you cannot configure default password reset email sent by Parse. If you want a configurable system, Parse provides two email modules in Cloud Code ([Mailgun](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-modules-mailgun) and [Mandrill](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-modules-mandrill)) which you can use to implement your own customized password reset mechanism.

So for example, when your user wants to reset their password, you email him a randomly generated code and save it with an expiry timestamp in your database. Then you ask your user to check their email and enter that code in the password reset page. You simply need to check the validity/expiry of the code before resetting their password.

Comment: Mo, thank you very much, but this does not answer my question. I know about Mailgun, etc. I simply need to know when the created password links expire, if ever.

Comment: You need to ask that from Parse engineers as the would only know. I simply tried to point you towards a home-brewed alternative solution.